# Prevent UITextField from focusing by checking a condition?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to check a condition when an user touches up into a `UITextField`, to prevent it from focusing and showing the keyboard in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method that is available in `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if condition {  // Specify your condition
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```